# Pivot data in pandas using melt and unstack

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-melt

Given the following data:

```py
data = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "A": ["a", "a", "b", "b"],
        "B": ["x", "y", "p", "q"],
        "C": ["one", "two", "one", "two"],
    }
)
```

which looks as:

```
   A  B    C
0  a  x  one
1  a  y  two
2  b  p  one
3  b  q  two
```

I would like to create the following:

```py
data_out = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "A": ["a", "b"],
        "one": ["x", "p"],
        "two": ["y", "q"],
    }
)
```

which looks as:

```
   A one two
0  a   x   y
1  b   p   q
```

I'm aware that I could do something along the lines of:

```py
d_piv = pd.pivot_table(
    data,
    index=["A"],
    columns=["C"],
    values=["B"],
    aggfunc=lambda x: x,
).reset_index()
```

which gives:

```
   A   B    
C    one two
0  a   x   y
1  b   p   q
```

from which the columns could be cleaned up, but I'm wondering how I'd go about solving this using melt and unstack?

I have tried:

```py
print(data.set_index("C", append=True).unstack())
```

which gives:

```
     A         B     
C  one  two  one  two
0    a  NaN    x  NaN
1  NaN    a  NaN    y
2    b  NaN    p  NaN
3  NaN    b  NaN    q
```

The NaN values aren't wanted here, so I could instead try:

```py
data.index = [0, 0, 1, 1]
data.set_index(["A", "C"], append=True).unstack(-1).reset_index(level=-1)
```

which gives:

```
   A   B    
C    one two
0  a   x   y
1  b   p   q
```

So that's closer - but it still feels as though there's still some unnecessary bits there.

Particularly coding the index like that.

## Edit

Solution of :

```py
df.set_index('A').pivot(columns='C', values='B').reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1)
```

is good, but I am wondering whether `unstack` can be used here instead of pivot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, set `A` column as the index then use `df.pivot`. To get the exact output we have to reset index and rename axis.

```
(df.set_index("A").pivot(columns="C", values="B")
                  .reset_index()
                  .rename_axis(None, axis=1))


   A one two
0  a   x   y
1  b   p   q
```

Using `df.unstack`

```
df.set_index(["A", "C"])["B"].unstack().reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1)

   A one two
0  a   x   y
1  b   p   q
```

Comment: thanks - can unstack not be used here? If not, how come?

Comment: @baxx Why not? It can be used. Edting the answer.